# Trying to create a URL in my JSON, but not sure if this is the right way

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how I would like to have it in my JSON (this is an example):

```
"audio": "https://test.diglin.eu/media/audio/nl_NL/bal.mp3"
```

how my code looks like:

```
exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'] = 
$(this).find('input.exerciseGetWordInput').val();
var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
var audio_link = '';
 if (audioId > -1) {
  exObject['audio'] = 'https://test.diglin.eu' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[audioId];
    }
```

the code above should be implemented into my function, but I don't know how to pass this on to my ajax call exactly.

The function where it all happens:

```
function setMainObjectArray() {
var exercises = [];
var eBlocks = $('.eBlock');

eBlocks.each(function(i, eBlock) {
    var exObject = {
      word: $(eBlock).find('input.ExerciseGetWordInput').val(),
      syllables: [],
    };

      exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'] = $(this).find('input.exerciseGetWordInput').val();

    var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
    var audio_link = '';
    if (audioId > -1) {
        exObject['audio'] = 'https://test.diglin.eu' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[audioId];
    }

    $(eBlock).find('input.syllable').each(function(j, syll) {

      exObject.syllables.push($(syll).val());            
    });

    exercises.push(exObject);
  });

return exercises;
}
```

my ajax call:

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
  console.log(setMainObjectArray());


    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveJson.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: getUrlParameter('id'),
            getExerciseTitle: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
            language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
            application: 'lettergrepen',
            'main_object': {
              title: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
              language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
              exercises: setMainObjectArray()
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            }
    }).done(function(response) {

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(errorThrown);
      console.log(textStatus);
    });
}
```

ur most likely wondering why I just don't give it a try and see what happens (or you could use the argument: Why don't you test it with a JSON validator? This because I have done such thing once before and my application crashed all the way. yet the JSON validator gave me "valid JSON").

EDIT: So you can see the complete JSON, it should look something like this:

```
{
"exercisetitle": "dedew",
"application": "",
"language": "nl_NL",
"id": "new",
"main_object": {
"title": "dedew",
"exercises": [
  {
    "word": "aap",
    "audio": "https://test.diglin.eu/media/audio/nl_NL/aap.mp3"
  }
]
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you've not actually run this code, but are asking if it's correct or not??  Also, I don't see any attempt to use the `.audio` value anywhere.

Comment: Well, I did run it in the validator of JSON, but yes. I know this is NOT how stackoverflow works. But after I messed up something so bad prior to this i'm not entirely sure whether the validators are correct. I don't often work with audio URL sending over to JSON files either, so I was atleast hoping to be pointed out in the right direction. I would rather have a few down votes but to gain knowledge from it then not give it a try at all and ruin everything again. so to wrap it in a short answer on ur question: No, I did not run this code, I am asking whether it's correct or not.

Comment: you also stated I am not attempting to use the audio value anywhere, but am I not doing this in the piece where I create the whole set-up for the audio? As my post refers, from my point of view I think I don't need to implement it into my ajax call since I already made the part where it should assign a value to ' audio'

Comment: No - you're setting the value of `exObject.audio` in 2 places, but I don't see it actually used anywhere.  Also, you return the value `exercises` from your function, but you're not using that value anywhere either.  `console.log(setMainObjectArray());` will execute the function, log the return value and then do nothing else.  You're not using the return value in any other way.

Comment: So... to keep it short: The code sucks big time. Correct?

Comment: If you don't want me to help you then just say so, otherwise try to continue the conversation without taking everything as a personal insult.  Please notice that I've not been derogatory and have neither downvoted or voted to close.

Comment: I do not take it as personal, I guess you took the comment in the wrong way haha. What I meant more was: MY code sucks big time. NOT: I don't appreciate your help. I surely DO appreciate the effort and time you put into this to explain and try to help me out. To drop back from the misunderstanding we just had, what do I have to do and what do I have to adjust to successfully send the audio like in the example in my post to my JSON?

Comment: Okay, then you're going to have to explain how you want to use the `audio` property as it's not clear.

Comment: Well, I want to create a variable "audio" that should be send to my JSON file combined with the word and syllables, each "word" also has an audio display from a server, I should make this into an mp3 (just like in the post above stated/shown) so I can call that back in the front-end so it can display the audio in the front-end aswell. Right now I am just trying to send it TO JSON. Create a variable "audio" that contains the url, the language, the word. I hope this was clear enough? If not, please elaborate on what you're looking for specifically.

Comment: Okay - you do actually send the array as part of the AJAX call data property (I missed that you call the function twice).  `saveJson.php` should be able to access the data.  You're going to have to run and debug this - it looks like it should pass the data correctly.

Comment: I do get an error when I try to run the code (I tried to run it, seemed much more logical then to just assume stuff). It says: Cannot read toLowerCase of undefined, and then it does not send anything to my JSON file or even create a new JSON file.

Comment: `exObject['exerciseGetWordInput']` must be undefined then.  You'll obviously need to fix that before you can proceed.

Comment: but how can it be undefined? I have it right there in exObject??

Comment: This is going way off scope and I'm leaving now, but I'll give you this information before I go.  Check the value of `$(this).find('input.exerciseGetWordInput').val();` and also check the class name is correct (you use the same class name elsewhere but with an uppercase letter at the beginning).